D10 Commerce 2 Update Payment Status with PATCH Call to the REST Ressource dont work : ACCESS DENIED
Drupal 10.2.5 with Commerce 2.8
Under /admin/config/services/rest i activated the Payment REST Ressource.
This provides the methods GET, PATCH and DELETE under the following path : /entity/commerce_payment/{commerce_payment}
Under the path /entity/commerce_payment POST is also available.
GET, DELETE and POST work as desired, only with PATCH I always get an Access Denied.
I get my CSFR token via /user/login and can use all other methods with it. Even with POST, complete payments can be created.
But PATCH does not work. However, I need PATCH to set an existing manual payment (bank transfer) to Completed on receipt of payment.
The user is the admin, he has all rights.
Here is the error message from the log file:

Path: /en/entity/commerce_payment/10?_format=json.
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException: in
Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->checkAccess() (line 118 of
/var/www/xxxxx/xxxxxxx.de/xxxxxxxx/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/AccessAwareRouter.php).

I have already tried various attributes, but in my opinion it cannot be due to the JSON, as I already get the access denied in Postman.
{    
    "type": [
        {
            "value": "payment_manual"
        }
    ],
    "payment_gateway": [
        {
            "target_id": "bank_transfer",
            "target_type": "commerce_payment_gateway"
        }
    ],
    "payment_gateway_mode": [
        {
            "value": "n/a"
        }
    ],
    "order_id": [
        {
            "target_id": 1825,
            "target_type": "commerce_order"
        }
    ],
    "amount": [
        {
            "number": "43.000000",
            "currency_code": "EUR"
        }
    ],
    "state": [
        {
            "value": "completed"
        }
    ]
}

Would be great if someone here could provide some info.
Greetings Maik
